# What is really happening behind when a constant is assigned to a pointer variable?

Tags: c

int *a = 3;
As per my knowledge, a pointer only accepts address. But here a pointer accepts a constant. Is there any implicit casting happening here.

Comment: Yes, there is an implicit cast from type `int` to type `int *`.  Most compilers will warn about it.  You'll end up with a pointer to address `0x0000003`, which probably isn't going to work, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @Steve Please do not answer in the comments section. You can review our Q&A model [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Thanks!

Comment: So , only the address of 3 is stored in the pointer a , as I have understood

Comment: @Allan No, not the address of 3. 3. Actually 3.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an implicit conversion (no such thing as an "implicit cast"; a "cast" is an explicit conversion) from `int` (the 3) to `int*`.

You are forming a pointer to the `int` at memory address 0x03, which probably doesn't exist, so don't do this.

The feature can be useful in some low-level settings, such as when memory mapping some hardware register in embedded circumstances. You get the address from the hardware's manual/documentation then write it into your code.

But, in general, if your compiler did not warn you away from such antics, turn up your warnings.

Comment: thanks very much . But how can i know if the memory address doesn't exit

Comment: @Allan: You can't — I would not expect any contemporary time-sharing operating system to put valid objects at 0x03 but, even if it did, you'd be quite lucky for an `int` to just _happen_ to exist at that particular place. That's why this is usually bad code. You should get addresses of things using the `&` ("address-of") operator.

Comment: the value 3 must be stored in memory somewhere . Then it should have a address . That address is being stored to the pointer variable. Is my understanding right?

Comment: @Allan No, the value 3 is part of the logic of your program. It does not need an address. Though after you assign it to the pointer, the pointer _may_ have an address, depending on how you use it. It's best not to try working out low-level details like this, because they vary, and they don't matter.

Comment: @Allan What is it that you are trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: Thank you LIghtness . Now i understand